Pytest Config removal of package scope fixture is not correct
I am trying to execute the pytest test suite, where I have some session level config, package level config.
In below mentioned folder structure, I want the testflow as below

Session level config,
package1 level config,
all tests in folder 1,
package1 teardown ,
package2 level config,
all tests in folder 2
package2 teardown ,
session teardown,

However i see pacakge1 tear down executed after package2 teardown. Am i doing something wrong here.
Actual vs desired o/p
files under folder 2
files under folder 1
conftest
folder structure

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please do not link to your code not post images of it.  Instead, type out your code in your post.
